# SQL: How to count number of each vowel separately in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

First of all, I am a beginner in SQL.

I have a column called `State` in a table where I have data as shown below

```
State
Karnataka
Uttar Pradesh
Tamilnadu
Telangana
Kerela
Andhra Pradesh
```

I want to know how many vowels are present in each state and the result should be separate for each vowel.

Expected output:

```
State         Count of a   Count of e   Count of i   Count of o   Count of u
Karnataka     4            0            0            0            0
Uttar Pradesh 2            1            0            0            1
```

Comment: This really smell like a homework. Next time at least try something first otherwise you never learn.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, Sure! Thanks

Comment: The fact that it's academic instead of employment is irrelevant to some of us.  This is a hard question so if it is homework, compliments on picking a challenging course.  However, you'll get more out of it if you try things yourself first.

Comment: @DanBracuk, Thank you for your advice.I tried first but didn't shown it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try below SQL:

```
SELECT 
State,
LEN(state)-LEN(REPLACE(state,'a','')) 'Count of a',
LEN(state)-LEN(REPLACE(state,'e','')) 'Count of e',
LEN(state)-LEN(REPLACE(state,'i','')) 'Count of i',
LEN(state)-LEN(REPLACE(state,'o','')) 'Count of o',
LEN(state)-LEN(REPLACE(state,'u','')) 'Count of u' 
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 1):

Using PIVOT:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST ([STATE] NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('Karnataka'     )
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('Uttar Pradesh' )
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('Tamilnadu'     )
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('Telangana'     )
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('Kerela'        )
INSERT INTO #TEST VALUES ('Andhra Pradesh')

SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT [STATE], N, LEN([STATE]) - LEN(REPLACE([STATE], N,'')) AS VOWELCOUNT
FROM #TEST
CROSS JOIN  (VALUES('A'),('E'),('I'),('O'),('U')) AS A(N)
) PVT
PIVOT (MAX(VOWELCOUNT) FOR N IN ([A],[E],[I],[O],[U])) AS D
```